# NServicebus - Tapping ServiceControl MessageFailed event

Tags: nservicebus

I came across this link that shows how to tap into Servicecontrol events.
http://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/contracts#servicecontroleventsxmlconfig-v3_x-5_x

While implementing this, just thinking how the persistence works here. What do i use as the persistence store? I my prod environment, i have implemented SQL persistence. Since servicecontrol has RavenDB as its persistence store, do i use the same storage i.e RavenDB?
Any one has example of how this configuration would look like?

Answer (score 0):

You are free to use whatever persistence store you want.  You are simply subscribing to service control's events here, so service control's internal persistence shouldn't matter to you.  The only thing that does matter here is that you configure your endpoint to use json serialization as shown in the article.

Answer (score 0):

Service Control uses a RavenDB for holding onto the messages for errors and auditing purposes. It exposes this information via an API that Service Pulse and Service Insight can consume. You don't need to worry about the fact that it's using RavenDB as a persistence when you are trying to subscribe to messages. That's just an implementation detail of Service Control.

The persistence isn't as important as the transport you've configured. If you are using SQL Transport, then Service Control has added tables (queues) to your NSB Transport database that you've setup. Service Control listens to messages in your app the same way your other NSB hosts do, via the transport you've configured.

If Service Control is currently working, then you are ready to go. You simply subscribe to those events and define the endpoint like you would with any of your other NSB Hosts. From the documentation:

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
  <MessageEndpointMappings >
    <add Assembly="ServiceControl.Contracts" 
         Endpoint="Particular.ServiceControl" />
  </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

Remember, when you (or your team) configured Service Control, they had to specify the transport it uses to be the same as the rest of your NSB Hosts.

Comment: I get the following error when starting my endpoint:

ERROR NServiceBus.GenericHost Exception when starting endpoint.
System.Exception: No persistence has been selected, please select your persistence by calling configuration.UsePersistence<T>()

Comment: I am not able to get this work for some reason. The question is, my host is installed under D:\NServiceBus\**********.NsbAudit.QueueService and ServiceControl is installed under C:\Program Files (x86)\Particular Software\ServiceControl.

I see the messages in servicecontrol log:
2016-02-16 18:31:04.5882|300|Info|ServiceControl.EventLog.GenericAuditHandler|Event: MessageFailed emitted
2016-02-16 18:31:04.5882|48|Info|ServiceControl.EventLog.GenericAuditHandler|Event: MessageFailed emitted
2016-02-16 18:31:05.1498|181|Info|ServiceControl.EventLog.GenericAuditHandler|Event: MessageFailed emitted

Comment: @HarshNanchahal Use the same persistence and transport as the rest of your hosts. Persistence does not mean where the queued messages are stored.